# Console function not defined error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I do not understand why my function isn't working and why I keep getting a "test is not defined error" when I try to run it.

I want the page to scroll down to the appropriate section, when the user clicks the right menu item.

```
<ul class="timelineNav">
            <li class="navItem">
               <button type="button" onclick='test("1")'>
                   Event1
               </button>
            </li>
            <li class="navItem"><a class="navItem"    href="url">Event2</a></li>
            <li class="navItem"><a class="navItem" href="url">Event3</a></li>
            <li class="navItem"><a class="navItem" href="url">Event4</a></li>
            <li class="navItem"><a class="navItem" href="url">Event5</a></li>
</ul>

    <article id="post1"> 
            some text
    </article>
    <article id="post2"> 
            some text
    </article>
    <article id="post3"> 
            some text
    </article>
```

Javascript function:

```
function test(postLocation){
var post = $('#post'+postLocation).offset();
$(window).scrollTop(post.top);

};
```

I originally wanted to make the list item itself start the function, but I guess it has to be a button?

Comment: rename test to findPost or findPost to test()

Comment: Sorry! test is defined in the javascript. I changed the name from findPost to test...but even with test() (changed it above) I get/got the same problem.

Comment: You are not passing `postLocation` right?

Comment: Another mistake from fumbling around. I've updated the code to make it clearer what I'm trying to do.

Users suggest adding the onClick event in the javascript, but is there another way? I'd hate to have to update both the html and javascript every time I add a new post/menu item. It would be nice to just add a new article and list item and give the article a new ID one javascript function can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show where the function `test()` is defined, but if it is inside a document-ready handler (or any other function), it is not in the global scope, so it cannot be called from an `onclick` attribute.

Either:

(1) Stop using an `onclick` attribute and bind a click event handler to the elements.

(2) Move the definition of the function outside the document-ready handler.

(3) Defined the function like this:

```
window.test = function(postLocation) {
    var post = $('#post'+postLocation).offset();
    $(window).scrollTop(post.top);
};
```

Also, you do not have to use a button. You should be able to make it so the function executes by a click on a list item.

---

I suggest the following:

HTML:

```
<ul class="timelineNav">
    <li><a href="#post1">Event 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#post2">Event 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#post3">Event 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#post4">Event 4</a></li>
</ul>

<article id="post1"> 
    some text
</article>

<article id="post2"> 
    some other text
</article>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.timelineNav').children('li').children('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $article = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $(window).scrollTop($article.offset().top);
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/548Pw/)</kbd>

Although the `<a>` elements are not needed, they do cause the mouse pointer to change.

Comment: Thanks!!
Your Fiddle really helped. I am still not sure why I cant you the onclick funtion on a button inside HTML. But your way worked and I understand how.

Comment: @user2559519 - The first part of my question addressed the issue of why you could not call your function from an onclick attribute and how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated HTML**

Added the id to the button for better jquery selection

```
<ul class="timelineNav">
    <li class="navItem">
        <button type="button" id="clickbutton">Event1</button>
    </li>
   ...
```

**JS**
Attach event to your button, remove inline event click

```
$(function () {
    $('.navItem').on('click', '#clickbutton', function () {
        var location = 1; //define or fetch your location here
        var post = $('#post' + location).offset();
        alert(post);
        $(window).scrollTop(post.top);
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/FN2Qf/)